# How to apply CSS style which will be ignored for tfoot or last TR

Tags: html, css

see the below css

```
.webgrid-table td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1)
 {
   display:none
 }
```

i just like to know how could i apply a style which will be applied for all tr except `last tr` or `tfoot`. guide me with that kind of css.

below html is a sample html for my table.

```
<table class="webgrid-table" data-swhgajax="true" data-swhgcontainer="gridContent" data-swhgcallback="initScripts">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=ID&amp;sortdir=DESC&amp;page=1">ID ▲</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=FirstName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">First Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=LastName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">Last Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=StateName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">State Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=CityName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">City Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                IsActive
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="webgrid-footer">
            <td colspan="6">
                <div id="content">

                    <div id="pager">
                        <ul class="paginate pag5 clearfix">
                            <li class="single">Page 5 of 5 of 50</li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">prev</a></li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">next</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">5</a></li>
                            <li class="current">6</li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="">next</a></li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="">last</a></li>
                            <li class="single"><div id="loader">Loading....</div></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">1</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Amit</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Ghosh</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Kolkata</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="SmallCols">2</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Tridip</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bhattacharjee</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bihar</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">DharBganga</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">3</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Dipyendu</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Majumdar</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Orissa</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Puri</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" value="False">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="SmallCols">4</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Arijit</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Banerjee</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Barrack Pore</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" value="False">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">5</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Madhabi</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Sinha</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Ranaghat</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the different selector like this, which doesn't include `tfoot`:

```css
.webgrid-table thead td:first-child,
.webgrid-table thead th:first-child,
.webgrid-table tbody td:first-child,
.webgrid-table tbody th:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

You are also leaving the `.webgrid-table` on the second rule, so it applies to all the tables, `tr:first-child`. Also I have replaced `:nth-child(1)` with more compatible `:first-child`.

Comment: if i need to hide second column then can we write this css `td:second-child` ? what would be right css to hide any column....may be first, second...5th etc?

Comment: @Thomas Ha ha... There's no second child man... Then you need to but `:nth-child(2)`. `:)`

Comment: @Thomas `.webgrid-table tbody td:nth-child(2) {display: none;}` `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` selector, which allows you to specify which elements you don't want styled. [More info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

```css
table > *:not(tfoot){
  color: red;
}

tr:not(:last-child) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="webgrid-table" data-swhgajax="true" data-swhgcontainer="gridContent" data-swhgcallback="initScripts">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=ID&amp;sortdir=DESC&amp;page=1">ID ▲</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=FirstName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">First Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=LastName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">Last Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=StateName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">State Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a data-swhglnk="true" href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?sort=CityName&amp;sortdir=ASC&amp;page=1">City Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                IsActive
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="webgrid-footer">
            <td colspan="6">
                <div id="content">

                    <div id="pager">
                        <ul class="paginate pag5 clearfix">
                            <li class="single">Page 5 of 5 of 50</li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">prev</a></li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">next</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/SamplePager/Index">5</a></li>
                            <li class="current">6</li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="">next</a></li>
                            <li class="navpage"><a href="">last</a></li>
                            <li class="single"><div id="loader">Loading....</div></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">1</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Amit</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Ghosh</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Kolkata</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="SmallCols">2</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Tridip</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bhattacharjee</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Bihar</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">DharBganga</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">3</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Dipyendu</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Majumdar</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Orissa</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Puri</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" value="False">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="SmallCols">4</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Arijit</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Banerjee</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Barrack Pore</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" value="False">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="SmallCols">5</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Madhabi</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Sinha</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">West Bengal</td>
            <td class="NameColWidth">Ranaghat</td>
            <td class="text-center checkbox-width SmallCols">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" class="box" name="select" checked="'checked'" value="True">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah i guess if you need to support IE8 and under